# How does the theme of fate manifest in 'Njal's Saga', and how does it differ from the theme of fate in the Aeneid by Virgil?

Tags: scandinavian-languages, latin-language, norse-mythology, aeneid, virgil

How is fate/fatalism portrayed in Njal's Saga? And how does it play into the development of the plot?

What are some comparisons that can be drawn between fate in Njal's Saga and the Aeneid of Virgil.

Comment: I wonder how this person finished their assignment and what grade they got on it...